# How to find highest probable matches between arrays

Tags: python, arrays

I have two arrays of clusters based on modularity.

Each array contains another array 2-7 names big, first name last name so there are no repeating names within an array, but there should be overlap between the two overarching arrays.

```
[[John, Mary], [Jane, Alex, Harry], [Rob, Sarah, Nadia]]  
[[Nadia, John, Mary], [Rob, Sarah, Eric], [Jane, Harry, Jake]]
```

I'd like `[Nadia, John, Mary]` to be returned with some certainty when inputted with `[John, Mary]` or `[Rob, Sarah, Eric]` to be returned when inputting `[Rob, Sarah, Nadia]`

Whats the best way to find the highest probable matches like this between two arrays of arrays?  Order doesn't matter

Comment: So, in other words, for each element from the first array, find the element from the second array that has the most elements in common? Does order matter?

Comment: No, order doesn't matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `max` with a special key function, counting the elements from the first sublist that appear in the second sublist.

```
for x in list1:
    y = max(list2, key=lambda y: sum(1 for w in x if w in y))
    print x, y
```

Or, as order does not matter, and names within one sublist are unique, use lists of sets instead and use set intersection:

```
    y = max(list2, key=lambda y: len(x & y))
```

Answer (score 0):

At the high level, I'd reduce each array to a vector of binary features (wherein you'd have a 0 if a given name wasn't present and a 1 if it was) and then compute the pairwise cosine distance of all the vectors. The vectors with lowest distance will have most names in common.

Alternatively, you could check out some [locality sensitive hashing methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing). This also sounds like possibly homework, so I didn't provide any code

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could use a `lambda` as the `key` argument of `max` to count the number of intersected elements

```
>>> s = ['John', 'Mary']
>>> max(l2, key = lambda i: len(set(s).intersection(i)))
['Nadia', 'John', 'Mary']
```

So you could use a list comprehension to make a list of matching lists from the 2nd list that line up with the first

```
>>> [max(l2, key = lambda i: len(set(j).intersection(i))) for j in l1]
[['Nadia', 'John', 'Mary'], ['Jane', 'Harry', 'Jake'], ['Rob', 'Sarah', 'Eric']]
```